# getting null exception in application

Tags: android, listview, textwatcher

in my app i want to filter the names and number according to entered text in the autocomplete,but it is returning me null pointer exception and my application get shut down.i am using same adapter for listview and autocompletetextview.how to get the list item starts with entered text by user.,please suggest something....

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener,
        OnItemSelectedListener {
    SearchView mSearchView;
    AutoCompleteTextView searchText;
    ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();


    String[] cellArray = null;


    String contacts;

    static int check1;
    ListView lv;

    String phoneNumber, name;


    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(
                Color.parseColor("#00aef0"));

        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);
        // mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

        getAllCallLogs(this.getContentResolver());
        searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        ma = new MyAdapter();

        searchText.setThreshold(1);
        searchText.setAdapter(ma);

        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);



    }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println(".............." + ma.mCheckStates.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

            {
                if (ma.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                    // phno0.add(name1.get(i).toString());
                    phno0.add(phno1.get(i).toString());
                    checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                    checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                            + name1.get(i).toString());
                }

            }

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", phno0);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

            finish();

            break;

        case R.id.addPage:

            break;
        case R.id.action_search:

            searchText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //String text_To_search= searchText.getText().toString().trim();
            searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    ma.getFilter().filter(s);



                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
        break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





            ma.toggle(position);

//
    }

    public void getAllCallLogs(ContentResolver cr) {
        mPeopleList.clear();
        Cursor phones = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " ASC");
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            System.out.println(phoneNumber);

            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);

            // meMap.put("name1","phno1");
            // mPeopleList.add(name);
            // mPeopleList.add(phoneNumber);

        }

        phones.close();

    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements  Filterable,
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        public SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        // public ListFilter listFilter;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1, tv;
        CheckBox cb;

        MyAdapter() {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }





        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            tv.setText(name1.get(position));
            tv1.setText(phno1.get(position));
            cb.setTag(position);

            cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;

        }

        public boolean isChecked(int position) {

            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);

        }



        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

**logcat**

```
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at com.example.smscampaign.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:193)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8366)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8428)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:10367)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:676)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:435)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:333)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-01 14:29:36.318: E/AndroidRuntime(12166):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post error log?

Comment: @ InnocentKiller please see it

Comment: What is line number 193 in `MainActivity.java`

Comment: ma.getFilter().filter(s); this is line 193

Comment: There you are not getting anything, your variable is not getting any value, check twice that you are passing right data to right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPE here:

```
ma.getFilter().filter(s);
```

and your `getFilter()` returns `null`:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

so calling `filter()` on the `null` causes the NPE.

You'll have to actually implement your unimplemented methods.